AdMob not showing on release build also signed apk(React Native)
I have implemented adMob in the React native app it was working in the debug mode, but it was not working on the release build, somewhere I found that after releasing it on Play Store, once Google verifies it the real ad will come. It's been 10 days since it was released, but still ad is not coming.
